# How to attach a file with FormData and Blob?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to attach a file and upload through ajax request. But it creates a new file instead of uploading the file I am trying to provide.

```
var formData = new FormData();
var blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify({})], {type : 'application/json'});
formData.append("file", blob, "sample.txt");
```

When I open the file I can see the content getting replaced with `{}`

Answer (score 0):

Code mentioned will only create and empty form object. If you need to upload that form object to server, use following similar code.

```
var formElement =  document.querySelector("form");
var formData = new FormData(formElement); //reads user input data from form

/**var blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify({})], {type : 'application/json'}); //added {} to form
formData.append("file", blob, "sample.txt");  //names file and keeps {} as content ----not needed**/

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", "http://foo.com/submitform.php"); //put ypur end point here
request.send(formData); //send to server
```

your form html should look something like this

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="submitform">

  <label>File to upload:</label>
  <input type="file" name="file" required />
  <input type="submit" value="Stash the file!" />
</form>
```

Please read more on this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects)